# Is it safe to return a member variable which is a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Suppose I have the following code, which is a simplified example of my problem:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class A{
  public:
  std::string name() { return "class A"; }
};

class B{
  public:
  B(){
    m_a = std::make_shared<A>();
  }

  std::shared_ptr<A> get_a() { return m_a; }

  private:
  std::shared_ptr<A> m_a;
};

std::shared_ptr<A> foo()
{
  B b;
  return b.get_a();
}

int main()
{
  auto a = foo();
  auto name = a->name();
  std::cout << name;
  return 1;
}
```

I was wondering is it safe to do so? "b" which is an instance of B will be released at the end of function foo. "a" in the main function is a shared_ptr of B::m_a. Is it safe to use "a" after "b" is released?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe duplicates ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643563/how-to-return-smart-pointers-shared-ptr-by-reference-or-by-value and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974964/best-practice-when-returning-smart-pointers ?

Comment: Please post compilable code. I.e. without syntax errors, with a correct `main` and with `#include`s.

Comment: I have read the two questions however I decided to post a new question because I want to make sure it is safe(or not safe) to do so event the "parent" class who hold the shared_ptr as member variable goes out of scope.

Comment: If that wouldn't be safe then I'm not sure I understand the point of shared_ptr's in the first place.

Comment: Christian and decltype_auto, you are right, I just edited the code to make it compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's safe. If this was not safe, then `std::shared_ptr` would be pretty useless.

> "b" which is an instance of B will be released at the end of function foo.

Yes, but its `std::shared_ptr<A>` is copied before that.

Let's look at what the last line of the function really does:

> ```
> return b.get_a();
> ```

`get_a()` produces a `std::shared_ptr<A>`, which is copied to a temporary object. This temporary `std::shared_ptr<A>` object is then copied again to become the result of the call in `main`.

<sup>*(Actual copies may even be elided due to return-value optimisation, but that doesn't change anything. If anything, it makes the safety even easier to understand.)*</sup>

Only *then* is `b` destroyed, but the `std::shared_ptr<A>` in it has already been copied by that time.

The `std::shared_ptr<A>` instance within `b` is destroyed, too, but the memory for the `A` object is *not* freed. **That's the whole point of `std::shared_ptr`** -- it knows how often it was copied and frees dynamically allocated memory only when the last copy is destroyed.

> "a" in the main function is a shared_ptr of B::m_a.

No. It's a `std::shared_ptr<A>`, but that's it. It has nothing to do with the original `B::m_a` anymore.

> Is it safe to use "a" after "b" is released?

Yes, because there is no lasting relationship between `a` and `b`.

---

Basically, you are questioning the safety a fundamental feature of C++, namely returning values from functions. Returning a `std::shared_ptr` is not different with regards to safety than returning a `std::string` or an `int`. That's always what happens when you return by value from a function: The to-be-returned value is copied, the original is destroyed, the copy lives on.

Answer (score 5):

That `foo`

```
shared_ptr<A> foo()
{
  B b;
  return b.get_a();
}
```

does not return a reference to a b member,  but a standonly copy (of a copy, if not RV optimized) of the member; and the `shared_ptr` a

```
auto a = foo();
```

saves the A heap instance from destruction until scope end.

Thus I consider this safe, the Bs, although creators, are after all just one user of possibly many of the shared assets they create and publish.

*In other words - the last one turns off the light, not the one who turned it on.*

[live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a765b26802c4e88f)

Answer (score 0):

It is safe.

`shared_ptr` creates a tracked variable on the heap.  This makes the object `B` more complex, as even when it is created on the stack, it allocates an `A` from the heap.  Possibly impacting performance.

When all users of the tracked data have stopped accessing it, then the `shared_ptr<>` is deleted.